# Activating mbstring in PHP after installing extension

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a trouble using functions of mb-string extension in PHP.
It is working well in Windows, but when I migrate to Linux server, it fails with error message. " Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding() in...".
I figured out that I need to install mb-string extension, and it was pretty simple.

```
yum install php-mbstring
service httpd restart
```

But the problem is that although I installed mbstring extension, that error still occurs.
I have tried php_info to check if the extension is installed, but I can't find mbstring on that list, even though if I run yum install php-mbstring again, it says "already installed, nothing to do".
Any ideas? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

you have to enable encoding: go to your `php.ini` change

```
;mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
```

to

```
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
```

you can change it to your required encoding:by visiting here:http://php.net/mbstring.internal-encoding

save and restart the server.

**Note:** you can change other related thing also by removing ; from the beginning ,if required.

Comment: same, no effect.